# Naudio mvc convert mp3 to wav

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, naudio

I would like to know if it is possible to convert mp3 to wave using nAudio library but without saving converted file to disc (using for example MemoeryStream) ?

[Link to nAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)

Any examples?

I tried like this:

```
byte[] fileStream = null;
MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
using (WaveStream waveStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(newMp3FileReader(filePath)))
using (WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(ms2,waveStream.WaveFormat))
                    {
                        byte[] bytes3 = new byte[waveStream.Length];
                        waveStream.Position = 0;
                        waveStream.Read(bytes3, 0, (int)waveStream.Length);
                        waveFileWriter.Write(bytes3, 0, bytes3.Length);
                        fileStream = bytes3;
                        return fileStream;
                    }
```

When I saved file from byte array it is damaged. 
Screen:

[image: Screen]

Comment: Your bytes3 just contains PCM, not a WAV file. You need to get the underlying byte array from the memory stream AFTER disposing the WaveFileWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to pass a MemoryStream instance to WaveFileWriter constructor, then write all the samples to the writer...  For the decoding side you can use the Mp3FileReader...

Good luck!

Comment: I posted code, can you tell me what could be a problem?

Comment: Mark nailed it...  Enjoy!